# Distribution of the maximum vector (over i.i.d. set) and its dot product with the eigenvectors spanning the rest.

Tags: linear-algebra, distributions, covariance

Let $z_1,\dots,z_n$ be i.i.d. draws from $N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a $p\times p$ matrix. Assume that $p>n$. Suppose (up to re-labeling) that $z_n=\max_i \|z_i\|_2$. Consider the eigenvectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ corresponding to the covariance $S_2=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} z_i z_i^T$

What is the distribution of the dot product: $z_n\cdot v_i$?

Comment: You're using the same notation, $z_n$, for two different things.  Did you mean you're going to re-assign the value of $z_n$?

Comment: Yes - relabel it. Without the loss of generality we assume that $z_n$ is the max.